# Laravel - retrieve the related model properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a data set (collection) that I retrieved using the following query:

```
Profile::where('profile.role', '=', 'hcp')->get();
```

The Profile model has a 'hasOne' relationship with a model named 'User'. I would like the above query to return the 'User' properties as well.

How could I do this?

Comment: Read the documentation. There's a 'with' method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
Profile::with('user')->where('profile.role', '=', 'hcp')->get();
```

Check the documentation on [Eloquent Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) for more info.